# How to get the height of an Image which download from URL in aspectFit mode Swift 4?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage, swift4

I have a `tableViewCell` which contains a `ImageView`.The image of the `ImageView` is download from a URL,so the height of every image is various.

So I use this code below to change the height of `ImageView` to display the image with different height:

**In `tableViewCell` class :**

```
let imageUrl = URL(string :"My url dynamic from API which different for every cell")

if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!)
{
  guard let actualImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: data) else{

     //do other thing here
  }

   let imageHeight = actualImage.size.height * actualImage.scale
   defaultItemImageHeightContrainst = ItemImageHeightContrainst.constant
   itemImageHeightContrainst.constant = imageHeight
   itemImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   layoutIfNeeded()

   //kingfisher
   itemImageView.kf.setImage(with: imageUrl)
}
```

By using the code above I can change the height of `ImageView` dynamically but the value of `imageHeight`(as declare above) is always 816,2520(This is extremely high),which produce the output below:

[image]

As you can see,it left a lot of blank space since the Image is not that tall.Cause I want my `Image` is in `Aspect Fit` mode.

After all the searching,I use this code below from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37894417/4332049) to set width and height of `imageView` in `tableViewCell`.This can reduce the blank space if the `imageView`,but it also cause the `tableView` very lag when I scroll the `tableView`

**New approach to resize the imageView**

```
func imageSizeAspectFit(imgview: UIImageView ,image : UIImage) -> CGRect {
    var newwidth: CGFloat
    var newheight: CGFloat
    //let image: UIImage = imgFeed.image!

    if image.size.height >= image.size.width {
        newheight = imgview.frame.size.height;
        newwidth = (image.size.width / image.size.height) * newheight
        if newwidth > imgview.frame.size.width {
            let diff: CGFloat = imgview.frame.size.width - newwidth
            newheight = newheight + diff / newheight * newheight
            newwidth = imgview.frame.size.width
        }
    }
    else {
        newwidth = imgview.frame.size.width
        newheight = (image.size.height / image.size.width) * newwidth
        if newheight > imgview.frame.size.height {
            let diff: CGFloat = imgview.frame.size.height - newheight
            newwidth = newwidth + diff / newwidth * newwidth
            newheight = imgview.frame.size.height
        }
    }

    print(newwidth, newheight)
    //adapt UIImageView size to image size
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    return CGRect(x: 0, y: 0,width: screenSize.width, height: newheight)
}
```

**So my question is :**

1) What is the correct way to change the height of a `ImageView` with `AspectFit` mode according to the actual height of the image that download from a 
   URL ?

2) If the code in **New approach to resize the imageView** section above is the 
   correct way then how to make the tableView not lag when scrolling?

Comment: you might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48385949/dynamic-cell-height-with-sdwebimage/48386279#48386279

Comment: ok thanks sir..I try to implement it,I tell you if I face problem..thanks